# Contents not being written to file using Java

Tags: java

I've following code for writing some string into a file.

```
String fileToWrite = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\testdata\\towrite.txt";
File file = new File(fileToWrite);
String toWrite = "This is to write to a file. Goodbye!";

FileWriter output = new FileWriter(fileToWrite);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);

writer.write(toWrite);
```

But when I open the file, I can see it empty. Means nothing is being written to it. Can you suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Close the `OutputStream`

Comment: just use writer.close()

Comment: Thanks Subash, Reimeus!